# Isnumeric() method not found

Tags: apex, sandbox, api-26

I have used isnumeric() method to check for the strings with only numbers.

While deploying to production i am receiving the following error 'Method not found '.

Answer (score 6):

isNumeric() is a new String Method in the Winter '13 release.

Your Production instance has not yet been updated from Summer '12 (API-25) to Winter '13 (API-26) yet but your sandbox has which is why your code will not deploy.

You will need to wait till your Production instance is upgraded to deploy your code. You should have recived an email with the title 'Winter '13 Release Notification' That contains the date. (Our instance is on EU1 and is scheduled for Friday, October 5 - Saturday, October 6, 2012)

http://developer.force.com/releases/release/Winter13/New+String+Methods

Some more Winter '13 release info for sandboxs:

http://blogs.salesforce.com/product/2012/07/winter-13-sandbox-preview-instructions.html

Comment: Production is still in summer 12,only sandbox has been updated to winter 13.

Comment: @VipulReddy Yep, this is why you cant can't deploy unfortunately. You will need to wait to deploy your code.

Comment: thanks for the reply.                              I had to deploy it today so i checked the string using the REGEX and Patterns for time being.